# Objective C - InputStream to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I'm kind of new on Objective C, so I'm trying to do stuff I usually do in Java, like converting an InputStream into a String.
Basically, I want to do this Java code in Objective C...

```
InputStream in = … //An inputStream i got from http request

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    str.append(line);
}

String myString = str.toString();
in.close();
```

I hope my problem is described clear enough! :)

Thanks!

Comment: `NSString * myString = [ NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:theURL ]`

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful, but that method is deprecated! But actually, theres an other method exactly like this which involves two more parameters. But thanks again, this was really helpful!

Comment: yes, sorry... use one of the other non-deprecated methods then. Of course, this is a synchronous call, so if you want UI performance you'll have to do something more sophisticated... like use `NSURLConnection` as others have suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Caleb is right, but answering to the question:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] init];
uint8_t buffer[1024];
int len;
NSMutableString *total = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
    if (len > 0) {
        [total appendString: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
}
```

Your `encoding` argument could be different.

Comment: +1 Good answer. For some reason I got distracted by the HTTP bit. However, you probably want to append `output` to a `NSMutableString` that accumulates the data -- right now you're leaking `output` and have no way to use the data from the stream.

Comment: Mmmh by the way, I don't understand why this code is leaking output. could you explain it to me @Caleb ... And thanks again!

Comment: @JoseLion There's no leak as it's written now. Originally, a NSString* called `output` was created with the bytes from `buffer`, but `output` immediately went out of scope and nothing else referenced the variable. It's not really a leak if you're using ARC (which will insert a `-release` call as soon as the object is no longer used), but it is if you're not using ARC. Either way, there was no way to access the string outside the body of the `if`. As written now, though, it's fine -- the new string is appended to `total`.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm kind of new on Objective C, so I'm trying to do stuff I usually do
>   in Java, like converting an InputStream into a String. Basically, I
>   want to do this Java code in Objective C...

Understandable, but trying to do those things the same way you do them in Java often doesn't work. Things aren't always done in Objective-C the same way that they're done in Java, so you can't just swap in new class names and fix up the syntax a bit. There's an `NSInputStream` class, but it's not typically used to download data from a web server. In short, you don't get an input stream from an http request. Instead, take a look at the `NSURLConnection` class and the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol. Indeed, there's a whole document called [*URL Loading System Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) that you should read. You'll create a `NSURLConnection` instance, give it a delegate, and let it do it's thing. The delegate's `-connection:didReceiveData:` method will be called as data comes in, and the delegate can do whatever it wants with the data, such as adding it to a string.

Comment: Good to know the ways are different, very informative answer by the way! Thanks!